# Polymer paper-dropdown-menu can't set and get selected value when binding with ngModel in Angular2

Tags: angular, polymer

I am trying to use polymer paper-dropdown-menu and paper-listbox. Now I am having problem in binding.

Here is dropdown list:

```
 <select name="singleSelect" [ngModel]="(person | async).department"> 
    <option *ngFor="let x of departments">
       {{x.name}}</option> 
 </select>
```

I converted into paper-listbox or paper-dropdown-menu

```
<paper-listbox #department 
        ngDefaultControl name="department" 
        [ngModel]="person.department" 
        label="department" > 
   <paper-item *ngFor="let x of departments"> 
        {{ x.name }} 
   </paper-item> 
</paper-listbox>

departments = [{name: 'HR'}, {name: 'IT'}, {name: 'Admin'}, {name: 'Management'}];
```

I couldn't get and set selected value.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu label="Department" #dropdown1>-->
<paper-listbox #department2 ngDefaultControl name="department2" class="dropdown-content" [ngModel]="(person | async).department"
    selected="{{(person | async).department}}" attr-for-selected="value">
    <paper-item *ngFor="let x of (departments|async)" [value]="x.label">
        {{ x.label }}
    </paper-item>
</paper-listbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Say you are trying to set the ngModel to a variable called `item.setting`.

For my usage, I am using `ngFor` to dynamically create a list of listboxes. You will need to make sure you include `import { ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';`. The function `setItemSetting()` will set whatever is selected on the listbox to `item.setting`.

```js
@ViewChildren('paperListbox') paperListboxes;

setItemSetting(index) {
  return this.paperListboxes.toArray()[index].nativeElement.selected;
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;">
  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Department">
    <paper-listbox 
      ngDefaultControl
      #paperListbox
      class="dropdown-content"
      (click)="item.setting = setItemSetting(i);">
      <paper-item value="0">Item 1</paper-item>
      <paper-item value="1">Item 2</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
</div>
```

If you only need one listbox, you can do something like this. In this example, you'll need to include `import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';`.

```js
@ViewChild('paperListbox') paperListbox;

setItemSetting() {
  return this.paperListbox.nativeElement.selected;
}
```

```html
  <paper-dropdown-menu label="Department">
    <paper-listbox 
      ngDefaultControl
      #paperListbox
      class="dropdown-content"
      (click)="item.setting = setItemSetting();">
      <paper-item value="0">Item 1</paper-item>
      <paper-item value="1">Item 2</paper-item>
    </paper-listbox>
  </paper-dropdown-menu>
```